# jquery link not working after removeClass('disabled')

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a script that disables links with a class "disabled"

```
//disabled links
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".disabled a").click(function() {
     return false;
   });
});
```

Additionally, I have a script that when the ".edit" button is clicked toggles the disabled state of the inputs in it's own form. It also does a removeClass('disabled') on any matching links in the form.

```
//toggle form edit
$("#edit").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest("form").find("input").prop('disabled',false);
  $(this).closest("form").find(".input-group-addon").removeClass('disabled');
  $("#save").prop('disabled',false);
  $("#edit").prop('disabled',true);
  $(".alert").hide(400, "swing");
});
```

Then there is a script for adding and deleting input fields

```
//add input fields
$(".form-group").on('click', 'a.addInput', function() {
  var original = $(this).closest(".input-group");
  original.clone().insertAfter(original);
});

//remove input fields
$(".form-group").on('click', 'a.deleteInput', function() {
  var original = $(this).closest(".input-group");
  if($(this).closest(".form-group").children(".input-group").length > 1) {
    original.remove();
  }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<form class="edit">
  <div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <span><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> Basic Information</span>
      <span class="pull-right"><input id="save" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Save" disabled></span>
      <span class="pull-right"><button id="edit" class="btn btn-default">Edit</button></span>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" value="engelo@dingosoft.us" disabled required>
          <div class="input-group-addon disabled"><a href="#" class="addInput text-success"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span></a></div>
          <div class="input-group-addon disabled"><a href="#" class="deleteInput text-danger"><span class="fa fa-minus"></span></a></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="phone">Phone</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="tel" class="form-control" pattern="\d{3}[\-]\d{3}[\-]\d{4}" placeholder="Format: 555-555-5555" name="phone" value="419-555-1212" disabled required>
          <div class="input-group-addon disabled"><a href="#" class="addInput text-success"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span></a></div>
          <div class="input-group-addon disabled"><a href="#" class="deleteInput text-danger"><span class="fa fa-minus"></span></a></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

The problem I am having is that when the class "disabled" is removed from the links, the links ('a.addInput') & ('a.deleteInput') do not function. What am I missing here?

Comment: try removing the disabled attribute instead of setting it to false

Comment: that part is actually working. disabled is not a valid attribute for anchors so I have to add a class and prevent default on it. that is the part that isn't working...removing the class, the prevent default is persistent.

Comment: Define "do not function".  Is that click handler in your first code snippet still being invoked?  Unless it was removed, I would expect it to still be invoked.  Because it was applied to those elements.

Comment: The document ready workflow that "disables the click" it's not the way to do it. Set a css property on the elements having that class: "pointer-events: none;"

Comment: @David right...so when I add and alert to the link click function, nothing happens so nothing is being invoked

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. https://www.bootply.com/9yZepoIrEO When I click edit I can still add and remove rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click handlers are attached to *elements*, not to *selectors*.  So when you do this:

```
$(".disabled a").click(function() {
    return false;
});
```

You are assigning that behavior to all elements which match *at that moment* (in this case, when the document loads).  No matter what changes you make to the DOM after the fact, any elements which were matched when you invoked the above code will still have the above click handler.

One approach here could be to assign the click handler to a common unchanging parent, instead of to the elements themselves.  By using `.on()` in this way, you can evaluate the selector dynamically when the click event happens instead of just once when the page loads.  Something like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".disabled a", function() {
    return false;
});
```

Then the second selector (`".disabled a"`) will be evaluated with each click.  So if the DOM has changed such that an element no longer matches that selector, this click handler won't be used.

Answer (score 1):

> You need to add prevent the event.

```
$(".form-group").on('click', 'a.addInput', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
  var original = $(this).closest(".input-group");
  original.clone().insertAfter(original);
});

//remove input fields
$(".form-group").on('click', 'a.deleteInput', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
  var original = $(this).closest(".input-group");
  if($(this).closest(".form-group").children(".input-group").length > 1) {
    original.remove();
  }
});
```

> or you can add a `href="javascript:void(0);"` to `addInput` and `deleteInput`.

I hope it will be help to achieve your goal...